# Trouble with edit button for To Do App JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, bootstrap-5

I tried creating an edit button for editing a created task, and it works for the very first task that i create.

1. However for subsequent tasks, the edit button for the respective tasks focus on editing the input on my first task again.
2. For every new task created, it changes the first task back to the very first original task that was written.

   To-Do List

   ```
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row mb-5">
            <div class="col h1 text-white text-start text-center text-md-start text-lg-start">TO-DO APP</div>
        </div>

        <div class="row">
            <div class="h6 text-white text-start text-center text-md-start text-lg-start">CREATE A TO-DO</div>
        </div>

        <form id="todo-form">
            <div class="row mb-4">
                <div class="col">
                    <input class="form-control" name="newTask" type="text" placeholder="eg. Do the laundry"> 
                </div>     
            </div>

            <div class="row">
                <div class="h6 text-white text-start text-center text-md-start text-lg-start">CATEGORY</div>
            </div>

            <div class="row mb-3">
                <div class="col-6">
                    <input type="radio" class="btn-check" name="category" id="option1" value="Work">
                    <label class="col-12 btn btn-outline-danger p-4 text-white work-task" for="option1">Work</label>
                </div>
                <div class="col-6">
                    <input type="radio" class="btn-check" name="category" id="option2" value="Personal">
                    <label class="col-12 btn btn-outline-primary p-4 text-white personal-task" for="option2">Personal</label>
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="row mb-4">
                <div class="col"><button type="submit" class="btn btn-secondary p-2 w-100 add-task" active>ADD TO-DO</button></div>
            </div>
        </form>

        <div class="row mb-2">
            <div class="h6 text-white text-start text-center text-md-start text-lg-start">TO-DO LIST</div>
        </div>

        <div class="todoList">

        </div>
    </div>
    <script src="main.js"></script>
   ```

Javascript

```
const todoForm = document.getElementById("todo-form")

window.addEventListener("load", () => {
    todos = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("todos")) || []

    todoForm.addEventListener("submit", (e) => {
        e.preventDefault()
        if (e.target.elements.newTask.value != "") {
            const todo = {
                task: e.target.elements.newTask.value,
                category: e.target.elements.category.value
            }
    
            todos.push(todo);
    
            localStorage.setItem("todos", JSON.stringify(todos));
    
            e.target.reset()
    
            showList()
        }
    })
    
    showList();
})

function showList() {
    let outPut = '';
    let taskListShow = document.querySelector(".todoList")
    const taskName = document.querySelector(".todoContent")

    todos.forEach((data, index)=> {

        outPut += `
        <div class="row todoList mb-3">
            <div class="col-10 col-lg-8 col-md-7 col-sm-6">
                <input class="todoContent no-border text-white text-center" value="${data.task}" readonly>
            </div>
            <div class="col">
                <div class="row action">
                    <div class="col-6">
                        <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary col-12" onClick="editItem()">Edit</button>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-6">
                        <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger col-12" onClick="deleteItem(${index})">Delete</button>
                    </div>       
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>`
    });
    taskListShow.innerHTML = outPut;
}

function deleteItem(index) {
    todos.splice(index, 1)
    localStorage.setItem("todos", JSON.stringify(todos))
    showList()
}

function editItem() {
    const taskName = document.querySelector(".todoContent")
    taskName.removeAttribute('readonly')
    taskName.focus()
    taskName.addEventListener("blur", (e) => {
        taskName.setAttribute('readonly', true)
        taskName = e.target.value
        localStorage.setItem('todos', JSON.stringify(todos))
        showList()
    })
}
```

How can make this work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since all of the input `class` will have `todoContent` and when you look for a class using `querySelector` then JS will return you the first matching element with class `todoContent`.

```
const taskName = document.querySelector(".todoContent")
```

[`CODESANDBOX LINK`](https://codesandbox.io/s/elastic-fermi-idf8r6?file=/index.html)

What you can do is look for all of the element with class `todoContent` and then take the particular input on which you have clicked by using the `index` of the clicked `edit button` as:

```
function editItem ( index ) {  // RECEVIVE INDEX
const taskAllName = document.querySelectorAll( ".todoContent" );
const taskName = taskAllName[index];  // USE SPECIFC ELEMENT
```

So you have to pass the `index` to function `editItem` as:

```
onClick="editItem(${index})">Edit</button>
```

Comment: I tried adding this to the code, and tried calling taskName.removeAttribute('readonly'). However i am receiving an "uncaught typeerror: cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'removeattribute')". Any reason why?

Comment: It is working as expected. You can take a look at the codesandbox link that I added in the code.

Comment: Ah okay it is working now thank you! Just wondering do you have a solution for my second problem? Right now when i save my edits and setItem to local browser storage, it doesn't really work as when i add a new task, the previous edited task changes back to its old task.

Comment: You shouldn't ask multiple questions in a single question. You can ask again.